# QT_VERSION_MAJOR not declared when compiling to 32 bits

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm working on porting an existing code from Qt4 to Qt5, and compilation works fine on 64 bits (the native system architecture), but fails with a strange error when I try to compile it to 32 bits:

```
$ QMAKESPEC=linux-g++-32 qmake-qt5
$ make
./create_version.sh
g++ -c -m32 -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSLT -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -Iinclude -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QCoreApplication:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:82:31: error: ‘QT_VERSION_MAJOR’ was not declared in this scope
     enum { ApplicationFlags = QT_VERSION
...
```

I guess this is not related to the code, since the error happens on the first line of my code, which is just an include directive, but don't know how to proceed from here. This is from a Fedora 23 system, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problema was a missing package: qt5-base-devel.i686
After installing it with

```
sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase-devel.i686
```

the problem was gone.

Comment: had the same problem but it was caused by broken missing devel files under `/usr/include...` i did check all the packages for missing files with `rpm -Va` then i reinstalled the problematic packages with `dnf reinstall ...` also it's useful to use `rpm -qf ...` to identify to which package belong a file...